# Fração própria, imprópria e aparente em linguagem C

Tags: c, if

Estou tentado criar o seguinte programa em C: Faça um programa que receba 2 números referentes ao numerador e denominador de uma fração e informe se é uma fração própria, imprópria, ou aparente.
Porém o código não executa a linha da fração aparente. Gostaria de saber o que estou fazendo de errado. Segue abaixo o código:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Seu codigo fica em preso em ```numerador >= denominador```. Se isso for true entao ele entra nesse else if. Sugiro que verifique primeiro se é aparente e no ultimo ```else if``` vereificar se é impropria

Answer (score 1):

Observe que sua condição para uma fraçao ser impropria so precisa `numerador >= denominador` e para ser aparente essa mesma condição dever ser verificada além da condição `numerador % denominado == 0`, mas a primeira condição ja é analisado no `else if` mais acima. entao o codigo entra no primeiro `else if`. Para corrigir troque a ordem das verificações, primeiro verifique se é aparente e depois se é impropria

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
  int numerador;
  printf("Digite o numerador da fracao: ");
  scanf("%d",& numerador);

  int denominador;

  printf("Digite o denominador da fracao: ");
  scanf("%d",& denominador);

  if(numerador < denominador){
    printf("\n A fração é propria");
  }
  else if(numerador >= denominador && numerador % denominador == 0){
    printf("\n A fração é aparente");
  }
  else if(numerador >= denominador){
    printf("\n A fração é imppropria");
  }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Entendi, deu certo aqui. Obrigada!